# Convert to correct BigDecimal representation

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have a string being returned as a data feed which I need to convert to the correct BigDecimal format - the string is of the format

1.6945E3

and needs to translate to 1694.50 but instead translates only to 1694.5 leading to loss of information. The following is the code I am using.

I am just passing the string and doing a new on a instance of BigDecimal.

Any ideas on how to get the correct data representation.

Thanks
'

Comment: "leading to loss of information" => what loss of information? Why do you expected 1694.50 and not 1694.500? etc.

Comment: 1694.5 it's equal to 1694.50; just a different formatter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it depends, try this

```
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("1694.50");
    System.out.println(bd);
```

output

```
1694.50
```

but this

```
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(1694.50);
    System.out.println(bd);
```

produces

```
1694.5
```

and this

```
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("1694.50");
    System.out.printf("%.3f", bd);
```

prints

```
1694.500
```